# How to open a chat tab by clicking on contact?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, onclick, chat

I'd love if you could help me out w/ this issue I'm having. I'm trying to create a list of contacts, like the following, and then be able to open a chat tab for that contact. Somehow,it seems like the JS isn´t working, I'd appreciate if you could give me a hand.

1st piece (HTML contact)

```
<div id="contact-list">
                <div class="contact-line">
                    <div class="status"><div class="online"></div></div>
                    <div class="user-photo"></div>
                    <div class="unread-wrap"><div class="unread">2</div></div>
                    <div class="contact-name">111111111</div>
                    <button onclick="createConversation(0)">Open Chat Tab</button>
                </div>

                ...

</div>

<ul id="ConversationsHeaderList">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="---.js"></script>
```

2nd Piece (JS)

```
var friendsList = document.getElementById("contact-list").getElementsByClass("contact-line").innerHTML;
var conversations = [];

function createConversation(contactindex) {

var auxvar = '<button><div class="ConversationHeader">' + friendsList[contactindex].getElementsByClass("contact-name").innerHTML + '</div></button>' + '<div class="status">' + friendsList[contactindex].getElementsByClass("status").innerHTML +'</div>' + '<div class="unread-wrap">' + friendsList[contactindex].getElementsByClass("unread-wrap").innerHTML + '</div>';

conversations.push('<li>' + auxvar + '<div class="ConversationClose" title="Close Conversation"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' + '</li>');

document.getElementById("ConversationsHeaderList").innerHTML = conversations;
```

}

Somehow, I can´t make it create something like this:

```
<ul id="ConversationsHeaderList">
    <li class="ConversationsHeader">
                        <button><div class="ConversationHeader">111111111</div></button>
                        <div class="status"><div class="online"></div></div>
                        <div class="unread-wrap"><div class="unread">2</div></div>
                        <div class="ConversationClose" title="Close Conversation"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("contact-list").getElementsByClass("contact-line")` isn't valid, same for other similar calls.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason. Does it work if I turn it into a ul and it's descendants into li?

Comment: Would it work if I wrote document.getElementById("contact-list").inner HTML. getElementsByClass("‌​contact-line")?